# How to join two table in hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

How to join table `Utente` and `Messaggio`?
id_utente is the PK for utenti while id_mittente is the FK for messaggi, and once I joined the two table I want all the rows where utenti.username is equals to a string username.

```
Entity Utente
@Entity
@Table(name="utenti")
public class Utente {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private int id_utente;
private String username;
private String nome;
private String cognome;
private String email;
private String password;
private int gruppo1;
private int gruppo2;
private int gruppo3;
private int gruppo4;
private int gruppo5;

public Utente() {
}

public Utente(String username, String nome, String cognome, String email, 
String password, int gruppo1, int gruppo2, int gruppo3, int gruppo4, int 
gruppo5) {
    this.id_utente = id_utente;
    this.username = username;
    this.nome = nome;
    this.cognome = cognome;
    this.email = email;
    this.password = password;
    this.gruppo1 = gruppo1;
    this.gruppo2 = gruppo2;
    this.gruppo3 = gruppo3;
    this.gruppo4 = gruppo4;
    this.gruppo5 = gruppo5;
}

}
```

Entity `Messaggio`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="messaggi")
public class Messaggio {
@Id @GeneratedValue
private int id_mess;
private String tipo_mess;
private String body;
private Timestamp timestamp;
private String tipo_destinatario;
private int id_destinatario;
private int id_mittente;

public Messaggio() {
}

public Messaggio(int id_mess, String tipo_mess, String body, Timestamp 
timestamp, String tipo_destinatario, int id_destinatario, int id_mittente) {
    this.id_mess = id_mess;
    this.tipo_mess = tipo_mess;
    this.body = body;
    this.timestamp = timestamp;
    this.tipo_destinatario = tipo_destinatario;
    this.id_destinatario = id_destinatario;
    this.id_mittente = id_mittente;
}
}
```

How can I write this SQL Query in HQL:

```
"SELECT * FROM messaggi m, utenti u WHERE m.id_mittente=u.id_utente AND u.username='" + username + "'";
```

Comment: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/current/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#hql. Read the remaining of the documentation too, while you're at it, because you're missing the whole point of an ORM.